# Spring boot with keycloak separate resource for backend services and users

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

I have simple architecture like:

[image]

backend microservice needs long duration token, like 2 days, and its service account so is authing with keycloak by grant_type: client_credentials

[image]

frontend of course serves users, so they use grant_type: password

[image]

and spring boot app has special API prefix for internal microservices calls
so /internal/ should be authed by this internal-client and other apis by fronted-client

in spring boot application.properties under .resource we can define just 1 `keycloak.resource` ( client ).

how can I deal with such scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

ok I managed to make it working.
It very simple,
in spring boot as a resource I need to keep this main one ( client for internal services ), but for frontend I need need to configure it.
Important is that in frontend client I have connected proper roles and thats it.